# Looking to implement redirects for entire website and a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am looking to implement the following.
if someone visits the site
oldsite.com or any of the pages under it they will be redirected to newsite.com

BUT
i need a specific page on oldsite.com to redirect to something else.

oldsite.com/page should go to newsite2.com

To summarize.
oldsite.com and any pages under that -> newsite.com
oldsite.com/page -> newsite2.com

I have tried using the Cpanel redirects but it doesnt seem to work for the specific page.

Adding

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

to htaccess file as well. I cannot seem to figure out how to do the last part of redirecting the specific url to another website while keeping the redirects to everything else.

Comment: Its not completely clear what you want. Is there only one page that you want redirected to a specific page on the new site? Or do you want all pages redirected to equivalent pages on the new site

Comment: So `old.example.com` and `new.example.com`. Everything on the former should go to the latter, **except**, `old.example.com/thing` needs to point to `thing.example.com/thing`. Something like that, right?

Comment: To clarify, you seem to want to redirect everything (except for one URL) to the _homepage_ on newsite.com? This is not great for SEO, if that is a concern?

Comment: @RiggsFolly basically example.com and all its child pages should go to newsite.com (straight to homepage , not to their respective copies) EXCEPT example.com/specialpage should go to newsite2.com

Comment: @RiggsFolly That (mod_alias) `Redirect` directive cannot be combined with the existing (mod_rewrite) `RewriteRule` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the more "simple" mod_alias directives:

```
# Redirect specific page
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page$ https://newsite2.example/

# Redirect everything else
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ https://newsite1.example/
```

Note the order of the directives. The most specific redirect is first.

This assumes the old-domain is not pointing to the same place as `newsite2.example` and/or `newsite2.example`.

You should test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

NB: Never mix redirects from both mod_alias (`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) since you can get unexpected conflicts. (mod_rewrite is always processed *before* mod_alias despite the apparent order of the directives in the config file.)

And, as mentioned in comments, if SEO is a concern then many-to-one redirects to the homepage like this are likely to be seen as soft-404s by search engines (and generally gives a bad experience for users).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your specific page first, then any 'remaining' URLs second:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myspecialpage$ http://www.specialdomain.com/myspecialpage [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect everything else to the homepage (not the same URL at the target domain), then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myspecialpage$ http://www.specialdomain.com/myspecialpage [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: They seem to want to redirect everything else to the homepage, not the same URL at the target domain.

Comment: exactly what @MrWhite said

Comment: I amended the answer to show how this could be done